# yum --download for CentOS with ubuntu?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, centos, yum, rpm

I have an enterprise network, people seems not willing to download rpm and dependancies **for CentOS**.

How can I

```
yum --download pkg_name --directory my_repo
```

in a system which do not use yum as packaging system such as Ubuntu or debian?

Comment: if your target system is ubuntu instead of centos then the package files are `.deb`  files instead of `.rpm` files.   debian and ubuntu use a different packagin system.

Comment: why do you want to just download instead of install?

Comment: I want to download packages for CentOS.

Comment: Can you run a apt-cacher proxy on the Ubuntu system? (Despite the name, apt-cacher can be used with rpm and pacman too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Debian has [yum-utils](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/yum-utils) available, which should have `yumdownloader`, which you can use to download RPMs from yum repositories.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the best way for apt-based distros like Debian or Ubuntu is to install `alien`, which converts individual `RPM`s into the native `deb` format, and then install them individually with `dpkg`.

Running as root:

```
apt-get install alien

alien package-name.rpm

dpkg -i package-name.deb
```

This obviously won't resolve dependencies automatically, and dpkg will refuse to install until they are met. Someone else might know a way to make this easier or automate it.

Comment: Sorry, I have miswritten : I want to downmload stuff for CentOS and not for the host distribution based on debian.

Answer (score 1):

You can save all the deb files with dependencies using the following command

```bash
apt install --download-only kubeadm=1.20.15-00
```

And the files will be stored under /var/cache/apt/archives

```bash
$ cd /var/cache/apt/archives

$ ls |grep kubeadm
kubeadm_1.20.15-00_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I think you missed the question asked.  The question was how to download CentOS packages on a Debian-based system.  Apt is not the right solution.